# Google App Script sheet that moves row to correct sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got this code to loop through each cell in Column A and check the cell value. If the value matches the if criteria it moves the entire row to the correct Sheet and then replaces the Column A cell with an X. This makes a call to the server for every cell and I'm curious if there is a way for me to optimize it similar to what Google has documented as [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices). The Cache service is confusing me.

[Here is a copy of the spreadsheet I'm working on.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DNND1A5-UROw2IoIGtTCQc77CcTjsHkZzpm08xJEPwE/edit?usp=sharing) The code has a menu execution under Move Row.

```
function moveToQA() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var columnNumberToWatch = 1;
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("QA ");

  for( var i = 3; i >= 3; i++ ) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(i,1);
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    if (cellValue == "Captures Sent " || cellValue == "QA In Progress " || cellValue == "Recapture Completed ") {
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
      cell.setValue("X");
    }
    else if (cellValue != "") {
      continue;
    }
    else if (cellValue == "" || cell == lastRow) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```